# viewDidLoad vs calling super viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working through objective-c tutorials and have noticed that the code in viewDidLoad is placed under super viewDidLoad rather than the first call to viewDidLoad.

What is the difference between putting code under viewDidLoad and under super viewDidLoad.

I understand a call to super is a call to the super class but not sure what that is in this context.

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 6):

The standard practice in iOS is to do all of your subclass setup after the superclass has completed the setup that it needs to do (initializing properties, laying things out, etc). If you don't give the superclass a chance to handle all of its setup before you start changing things around, it's possible you'll encounter some strange bugs and behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between putting code under viewDidLoad and under super viewDidLoad?

The order of execution. Your implementation will be executed after the superclass implementation(s) are run. Some implementations do nothing (that detail should be abstracted), but it will not hurt to call them (exceptions should be documented).

If you are looking for specific differences, that can vary greatly depending on the class hierarchy. You should just ignore those implementation details. Suffice it to say that the superclass implementations may not be prepared to handle your initialization until after the superclass implementation has been performed.

Rule of thumb (exceptions should be documented):

- When initializing/setting up, run the superclass' implementations first.
- When tearing down/cleaning up, run the superclass' implementation last.
- For other categories, you will typically want to run the superclass' implementations first.

Note the symmetry of the first two points in your implementations. Also, the superclass implementations may not be able to handle your requests (correctly) after you have run the superclass implementation.

Detailing `super`: Your objects exist in a hierarchy of objects. The superclass is the object you have derived from. Example:

```
NSObject >
UIResponder >
UIViewController >
UICollectionViewController
```

Assume `UICollectionViewController` implemented `-viewDidLoad`. Its implementation would call `super`'s implementation to ensure that all implementations in the class hierarchy are executed. This is similar to initialization -- when the superclass' initializer is called in initializers, ensuring that all initializers in the class hierarchy are executed in the correct order. Similarly, `-dealloc` is executed in reverse order (in ARC the compiler adds the call to `[super dealloc]` after your implementation has executed).